# how to change uilabel text size in different iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Is there a way to change UILabel text size for different screen sizes?

I need the text to be bigger in I-phone 6 and 6+.

Can i do this?

Would the correct way to do this will be to check screen height and then changing the text size?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah using sizeClass in stroyBoard, or programmatically you can do something like this
 `if (IS_IPHONE6) { [myLabel  setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:20]]; 
else if (IS_IPHONE6_PlUS) [myLabel  setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"digital-7" size:30]]`

Comment: what is sizeClass? i'm pretty new to ios dev. thanks

Comment: Size class allow you to create dynamic layout and  adaptative design for différent device size . Try to Google it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (self.view.frame.size.width == 320){
        //iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS, 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 5c
        label.font = UIFont(name: "....", size: 20)
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.size.width == 375){
        //iPhone 6
        label.font = UIFont(name: "....", size: 25)
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.size.width == 414){
        //iPhone 6 Plus
        label.font = UIFont(name: "....", size: 30)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the .pch file declare the following

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Use the following where you need to implement

```
if (IS_IPHONE_6){
        [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:18]];
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
        [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:20]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are convenience methods to determine the height of the current device from a library called Resplendent Utilities. You will first have to install the cocoa pod for this library here http://cocoapods.org/pods/ResplendentUtilities. If you can't install cocoa pods, you can simply get the needed code from the github link to this library https://github.com/Resplendent/ResplendentUtilities.

Once you have this library in your project, import this file https://github.com/Resplendent/ResplendentUtilities/blob/master/Pod/Classes/ResplendentUtilities/Code/ResplendentUtilities/Misc/Compatability/RUScreenSizeToFloatConverter.m

Once you have this file imported, init the class object of this file (RUScreenSizeToFloatConverter). You can then store the appropriateHeightForCurrentScreenHeight property of this class in a CGFloat. This property gives you the height of your current device. You can then use some conditional statements (if (appropriateHeightForCurrentScreenHeight == 736.0f) {}) to determine the size of your label text depending on the height of your device.

Comment: I'm using swift ... cant i just get the height with self.view.frame.height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use size classes to configure different styles and layouts depending on the screen sizes. At the bottom of Interface Builder in your storyboard, you'll see `wAny hAny`. Click that and you can select the size of the device you want to configure your styles to.