# How to set different font size for UILabel for different iPhones in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, uilabel

I've been trying to set different font sizes for different iPhone sizes. I researched a lot about this but couldn't find the proper way of doing it. All I found is [how to change uilabel text size in different iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236293/how-to-change-uilabel-text-size-in-different-iphones) which shows how to change the font size based on hard coded values that too programmatically. I'm looking for changing the font size using storyboard i.e adaptive layout. Another popular answer I found was to add wC hAny in storyboard. But, this can only be used to set the different font size for an iPad and iPhone(not for different iPhone sizes). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to set the minimum font size for the label. Then set your constraints so when the labels get squished in a tighter area the font will shrink to fit on the screen.